# Yajra datatables & materializecss dropdown on responsive

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have a dropdown menu inside a yajra datatable. That menu is built using the addColumn function and is working fine on desktop. However on mobile, the menu doesn't show on click. Here is my code:

```
->addColumn('status', function($orders) use ($orderStatuses){             
           
                $headerElement = '<span id="selectedValue" class="center-align dropdown-trigger chip lighten-4 '. $orders->status->styles .'" data-target="status-options-'.$orders->id.'" style="width: 110px;">'. $orders->status->localized . '</span>';
                if(Auth::user()->hasRole(['Super Administratör', 'Administratör']))
                {
                    $mainElement = '<ul id="status-options-'.$orders->id.'" class="dropdown-content">';
                    $bodyElement = "";
                    foreach($orderStatuses as $status)
                    {                    
                        if($status->id != $orders->status->id)
                            $bodyElement .= '<li class="center-align valign-wrapper"><span class="statusSelection center-align chip lighten-4 '. $status->styles .' valign center-block" data-status="'. $status->id .'" data-order-id="'.$orders->id.'">'. $status->localized . '</span></li>';
                    }
                        $footerElement = '</ul>';
                        $constructedElement = $headerElement . $mainElement . $bodyElement . $footerElement; 
                } 
                else
                {
                    $constructedElement = $headerElement;
                }       

                return $constructedElement;
            })
```

And the way I initialize the dropdown:

```
fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings ) {
    if(isAdmin || isSuperAdmin)
    {
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrainWidth: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: false, // Activate on hover
                gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
                coverTrigger: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
                alignment: 'center', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
                stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that works for me is to show that column by default on mobile since it looks like that the + button on datatables, adds the data dynamically to the DOM and as a result, the list is not rendered properly. So adding the list to the ones showing by default solved the issue without further coding.